# D3 force-directed graph - filter nodes and associated links

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am having difficulties with the filter that I am trying to use on my force directed graph. I can filter out nodes, but cannot make associated links disappear. My knowledge of JavaScript is pretty limited, but I guess the logic should be: if node is hidden, then hide associated links. Am I on the right path?
If someone could help me with it, it would be much appreciated!

Data format:

```
{
  "nodes": [
{"name":"AA1","group":"Group1","type":"a"},
{"name":"AA2","group":"Group2","type":"b"},
{"name":"AA3","group":"Group3","type":"c"},
{"name":"AA4","group":"Group4","type":"a"},
{"name":"AA5","group":"Group2","type":"b"},
{"name":"AA6","group":"Group4","type":"c"},...
],
  "links": [
{"source":1,"target":59,"value":1},
{"source":1,"target":88,"value":1},
{"source":3,"target":12,"value":1},
{"source":3,"target":16,"value":1},
{"source":3,"target":87,"value":1},
{"source":5,"target":3,"value":1},
{"source":5,"target":16,"value":1},
{"source":5,"target":114,"value":1},...  ]
```

FILTER CODE:

```
 // call method to create filter
createFilter();
// method to create filter
function createFilter()
{
    d3.select(".filterContainer").selectAll("div")
      .data(["a", "b", "c"])
      .enter()
      .append("div")
          .attr("class", "checkbox-container")
      .append("label")
      .each(function(d) {
         // create checkbox for each data
      d3.select(this).append("input")
        .attr("type", "checkbox")
        .attr("id", function(d) {return "chk_" + d;})
        .attr("checked", true)
        .on("click", function(d, i) {
            // register on click event
            var lVisibility = this.checked? "visible":"hidden";
            filterGraph(d, lVisibility);
        })
        d3.select(this).append("span")
          .text(function(d){return d;});
      });

      $("#sidebar").show();  // show sidebar
}

 // Method to filter graph
function filterGraph(aType, aVisibility)
{   
 // change the visibility of the node

    node.style("visibility", function(o) {
    var lOriginalVisibility = $(this).css("visibility");
    return o.type === aType ? aVisibility : lOriginalVisibility;
    });
```

///////////////////////////////////////
NEEDED CODE TO HIDE LINKS 
//////////////////////////////////////

```
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to hide the link by checking if either its source or target is not selected. So in your filterGraph part, add something like (suppose your links have class="link"):

```
positive = ["Dahlia", "Tholomyes"];
link.attr("display", function (o) {

////Here the structure of the the link can vary, sometimes it is o["source"]["name"], sometimes it is o["source"]["name"], check it out before you fill in.
var source_name = o["source"]["id"];
var target_name = o["target"]["id"];

var result = positive.indexOf(source_name) != -1 && positive.indexOf(target_name) != -1 ? "auto" : "none"

return result;

});
```

Take Mike Bostock's miserable for instance, I have used the code above to filter out all the others except the one that connects "Dahlia" and "Tholomyes".

[image]

Here is the snippet for your jsfiddle example:

```
var hidden_nodes =[];
 // Method to filter graph
function filterGraph(aType, aVisibility)
{   
 // change the visibility of the node
 // if all the links with that node are invisibile, the node should also be invisible
// otherwise if any link related to that node is visibile, the node should be visible
// change the visibility of the connection link


    node.style("visibility", function(o) {
        var lOriginalVisibility = $(this).css("visibility");
        if (o.type == aType) {
            if (aVisibility == "hidden")
                {
                    hidden_nodes.push(o.name);
                }
            else
                {
                    index = hidden_nodes.indexOf(o.name);
                    if (index > -1) 
                    {
                        hidden_nodes.splice(index, 1);
                    }
                }
        }
        return o.type === aType ? aVisibility : lOriginalVisibility;

    }); 


    link.attr("display", function (o) {
    ////Here the structure of the the link can vary, sometimes it is o["source"]["name"], sometimes it is o["source"]["name"], check it out before you fill in.
    var source_name = o["source"]["name"];
    var target_name = o["target"]["name"];


    var result = hidden_nodes.indexOf(source_name) != -1 || hidden_nodes.indexOf(target_name) != -1 ? "none" : "auto"

    return result;

    });
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I tried inserting it, and got an error: ReferenceError: positive is not defined

Comment: I can image you need some adjustment to make my code work in your script. Can you tell me the error and show your ".link" creation code please?

Comment: var link = svg.selectAll(".link")
    .data(graph.links)
    .enter().append("line")
    .attr("class", "link")
    .style("stroke-width", function (d) {
    return Math.sqrt(d.value); })
  .style("marker-end",  "url(#source)")

Comment: ReferenceError: positive is not defined
 

var result = positive.indexOf(source_name) != -1 | positive.indexOf(target_name)...

Comment: I guess you are taking Mike's miserable example bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4062045? I have edited my code, you need the positive =["Dahlia", "Tholomyes"] line

Comment: Thank you again. Now it hides all the links once I deselect one of the filter checkboxes and never brings them back. What are you referring to as "positive =["Dahlia", "Tholomyes"]" ? I am trying to use filter based on node type.

Comment: The 'positive =["Dahlia", "Tholomyes"]' is only a demo in Mike's example. In any case, you need to tell the "display" setter what nodes are shown. In my case, I ask it to check my "positive". Make the "positive" global, modify your filter part to fill the "positive" list and the rest will be done by my code. To recover the links, all you need to do is "link.attr("display", "auto");" when you uncheck your check box.

Comment: This is great! You are very helpful. I think I understand the logic now. The only thing is, how do I fill the "positive" list inside my filter?

Comment: if (o.type == aType) {positive.push(o.id);}

Comment: I have tried what you suggested, but unfortunately was unable to get it working. I have uploaded the code to jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Alexey_D3/t1L69th4/8/ Could you take a look at it, please?

Comment: This is very close to what I need, thanks a lot!  Lonely nodes are fine for my project. It seems like by deselecting only one type the graph looks accurate, however when I deselect 2 or more types, something wrong is going on.

Comment: Hi, you just need to go a little bit further to figure out the logic. Now I have corrected it and posted the solution in my answer above. Use my snippet to replace yours. By the way, by hiding some nodes, some other will become unconnected. For example, if AA1 is only connected to AA2 and vice versa. Now if you hide AA1, my function will also hide the connection between them, effectively making AA2 a lonely node.

Comment: What is wrong by "deselect 2 more types" please? I have just edited the code a bit, so please reupdate yours with my snippet.

Comment: It works! I can't thank you enough... This has been my headache for 2 weeks.

Comment: If you find my posts useful, please upvote my answer and check it as the solution. Thanks.

Comment: I will as soon as I get 15 "reputations".

Comment: Is there a way to add a "Select All/ De-select All" button in the filter?

Comment: Of course, more commonly you will add another checkbox that you can toggle. When you click on it, you need to programmatically (that is in jquery or something) to trigger the filter checkbox.